# NSSearchPathDirectory use of unresolved identifier

Tags: macos, cocoa, enums, swift

In my app I want to save some information for the user somewhere. I picked the Application Support Directory, which I am trying to get like so:

```
let savePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(ApplicationSupportDirectory, UserDomainMask, true)
```

Im getting a compile error in XCode saying "Use of unresolved identifier", even though the function is requesting a NSSearchPathDirectory type, which according to Apple's documentation clearly exists:

> enum NSSearchPathDirectory : UInt { 
>           case ApplicationDirectory 
>           ... 
>           case ApplicationSupportDirectory 
>           ... 
>       }

The same problem occurs with 'UserDomainMask'

Is this a bug or am I missing something? (Also, I would prefer not to use a workaround like substituting an integer literal...)

Comment: Prepend a `.` on `ApplicationSupportDirectory` and `UserDomainMask`, they are `enum` fields.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement is:

```
let savePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
println("savePath: \(savePath)")
```

output:

```
savePath: [/Users/zaph/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/24F94BD2-9DD7-4BC6-AA66-128AC1E7555F/data/Containers/Data/Application/9FFA8987-A36B-4A4D-A607-1BC220ADBBF2/Library/Application Support]
```

A leading "." is needed for the enumeration values.